# Case function with IS Null

Tags: teradata

How do I implement such scenario in Teradata

If Col1 is null or if Col1 = ''Jack'' then Col2 else Col1

I ha e implemented it but for some reason it's not working may be some issue with Bracketay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a case *expression*:

```
case 
  when col1 is null or col1 = 'Jack' then col2
  else col1
end
```

String (varchar) constants need to be enclosed in sinqle quotes in SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Replying 

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `NULLIF()` operator:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(col1,'Jack'), col2)
```

This is logically equivalent to the `CASE` statement in the previous answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Replying 